# How to use cellular/wifi network on my iphone application?

Tags: iphone, xcode, networking, wifi, cellular-network

I develop radio streaming iphone app.
I submitted it to app store, but rejected.
Because my app could not access streaming server.
(at this moment, I wonder why did my app plays on my iphone when I tested it)
After searching through internet, I found that I missed two plist propertys.
That are "Application uses WiFi" and "Required device capabilities".

So, could I conclude that 
**If I want to play the radio streaming via streaming server, then I must explicitely notify my app's plist to use WiFi?**

Is this right?

Additionally How to send & receive network data via cellular networK?
Just nothing to do? Or Anything to change(like WiFi)?

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the URL of the streaming server can be accessed from anywhere (not just your -local- WIFI network)?

Comment: Yes, there is no problem with the streaming server. I changed my question. Please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, You should test whether your libraries are correctly linked to your app.
And If you use wifi on your Iphone, then you should explicitely add your app's functionality(the use of wifi) in your plist. "Application uses WiFi", "Required device capabilities".

I recommend that your Iphone have reachability. If user use your app on celluar network, your app should acknowledge user to your app is using cellular network. The app store guide user to use reachabilty.
So I recommend it!

Comment: What the difference between `Application uses WiFi` and `wifi` (in `Required device capabilities`)? Why there are two of them?